# Using javascript class in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, hl7-fhir

I want to use a native `javascript` [library](https://github.com/FHIR/fhir.js) in my `Angular2` project. I built it and created a bundled `js` file. Now, I need only one class named `fhir` from this file. I tried to create a new `javascript` class and create an instance of the `fhir` class in it. Then, I am calling functions from that instance in my own functions:

```
/// <reference path='./FhirClient.d.ts' />

import { fhir } from './nativeFhir';

export var FhirClient = (function() {

    function FhirClient(config) {
        this.client = fhir(config);
    }

    FhirClient.prototype.conformance = function(query) {
        return this.client.conformance(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.document = function(query) {
        return this.client.document(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.profile = function(query) {
        return this.client.profile(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.transaction = function(query) {
        return this.client.transaction(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.history = function(query) {
        return this.client.history(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.typeHistory = function(query) {
        return this.client.typeHistory(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.resourceHistory = function(query) {
        return this.client.resourceHistory(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.read = function(query) {
        return this.client.read(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.vread = function(query) {
        return this.client.vread(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.delete = function(query) {
        return this.client.delete(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.create = function(query) {
        return this.client.create(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.validate = function(query) {
        return this.client.validate(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.search = function(query) {
        return this.client.search(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.update = function(query) {
        return this.client.update(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.nextPage = function(query) {
        return this.client.nextPage(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.prevPage = function(query) {
        return this.client.prevPage(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.resolve = function(query) {
        return this.client.resolve(query);
    };

});
```

And I created a `.d.ts` file for this class:

```
import { fhir } from './nativeFHIR';

export declare class FhirClient {
    private client: fhir;

    constructor(config: any);

    conformance(query: any): any;
    document(query: any): any;
    profile(query: any): any;
    transaction(query: any): any;
    history(query: any): any;
    typeHistory(query: any): any;
    resourceHistory(query: any): any;
    read(query: any): any;
    vread(query: any): any;
    delete(query: any): any;
    create(query: any): any;
    validate(query: any): any;
    search(query: any): any;
    update(query: any): any;
    nextPage(query: any): any;
    prevPage(query: any): any;
    resolve(query: any): any;

}
```

However, I didn't write a `.d.ts` file for the library I'm using.

When I tried to import my class (`FhirClient`) in the `Angular` and call a function from an instance of that class,

```
    this.client = new FhirClient(env.environment.server.config);
    this.client.search({type: 'Patient', id: 'pa000001'}).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

It gives  `... is not a function` error:

[image: error]

This is my first time trying to use a `.d.ts` file and probably I'm completely using it wrong. Can you help me to use the `fhir` class from the native library in my Angular project?

Comment: didn't you find typings available for this library?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you should wrap it in IIFE. Currently you do not execute your function: `export var FhirClient = (function() { ... })()`. You forgot `()`. Or your need `new FhirClient()()`

Comment: @VadimB I tried it like you said, now the error is `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__FhirJS_FhirClient__.a is not a constructor`

Comment: Yes, that because you need parameters-less constructor. So this approach is not working here. Try then leave as it was before and add return statement to get your correct cosntructor after import `return FhirClient;`.

Comment: @VadimB I couldn't understand where to return it. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: `export var FhirClient = (function() { ... return FhirClient; })`

Comment: @VadimB Now it gives `this.client.search is not a function` error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134960/discussion-between-bunyamin-sarigul-and-vadimb).

Comment: I've shared example whick works on my machine. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, as it works in my case:

Your exported class (yes, you need here IIFE and return class at the end):

```
import { fhir } from './nativeFhir';

export var FhirClient = (function() {

    function FhirClient(config) {
        this.client = fhir(config);
    }

    FhirClient.prototype.conformance = function(query) {
        return this.client.conformance(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.document = function(query) {
        return this.client.document(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.profile = function(query) {
        return this.client.profile(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.transaction = function(query) {
        return this.client.transaction(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.history = function(query) {
        return this.client.history(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.typeHistory = function(query) {
        return this.client.typeHistory(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.resourceHistory = function(query) {
        return this.client.resourceHistory(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.read = function(query) {
        return this.client.read(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.vread = function(query) {
        return this.client.vread(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.delete = function(query) {
        return this.client.delete(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.create = function(query) {
        return this.client.create(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.validate = function(query) {
        return this.client.validate(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.search = function(query) {
        return this.client.search(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.update = function(query) {
        return this.client.update(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.nextPage = function(query) {
        return this.client.nextPage(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.prevPage = function(query) {
        return this.client.prevPage(query);
    };
    FhirClient.prototype.resolve = function(query) {
        return this.client.resolve(query);
    };

    return FhirClient;
})();
```

Usage:

```
this.client = new FhirClient(env.environment.server.config);
```

Comment: The last form I tried was that, and it gives `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function` error at `main.bundle.js`. When I looked at the `main.bundle.js` this line is the `this.client = __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__nativeFhir__["fhir"])(config);`. It should be the `this.client = fhir(config);
` line at the js file. I think the problem is how I imported the `fhir` class.

Comment: How do you import this class? `import {FhirClient} from "...";` ?

Comment: No, I mean how I imported the `fhir` from `nativeFHIR.js`: `import { fhir } from './nativeFhir';`

Comment: No, I mean before using `this.client = new FhirClient(env.environment.server.config);` you need to import `FhirClient` first. Do you have this in your imports `import {FhirClient} from "path-to-file";` ?

Comment: Yes, I have imported it. And now, I removed the `import { fhir } from './nativeFhir';` line from the `FhirClient.js`, and instead I added `<script src="app/shared/FhirJS/nativeFhir.js"></script>` to the index.html. Now it worked. But I don't want to import it in `index.html`, I wanted to make it like a seperate module.

Comment: `console.log(ftir)` after import will show you maybe you have some problems with path or module

Comment: It has a line `module.exports = fhir;` and two files are in the same folder. Should I use something like `require()` instead of `import {fhir} ...`?

Comment: No, you don't. Just print to console this `fhir` after import to be sure it imported successfully.

Comment: It prints `undefined`.

Comment: I changed `import { fhir } from './nativeFhir';` to `import fhir from './nativeFhir';` and now it is imported correctly.

Comment: Yes, I am confused but happy :) Thank you for all your help!